# Accessing GSL Library with Cython

Tags: cython, gsl

I am trying to use the GSL library in a Cython program but don't seem to have the paths correctly specified; I encounter the following error when I try writing a simple example:

```
%load_ext cythonmagic
%%cython -lgsl -lgslcblas

cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_ran_poisson_pdf.h":
    double gsl_ran_poisson_pdf(int x, double mu)

    def poison(int x, double mu):
        return gsl_ran_poisson_pdf(x,mu)

   /Users/name/.ipython/cython/_cython_magic_189673701925d12059c18b75663da8bd.c:317:10: fatal error: 
  'gsl/gsl_mode.h' file not found
  #include "gsl/gsl_mode.h"
```

I get the same error using CythonGSL and the demo program here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/twiecki/CythonGSL/blob/master/examples/cython_gsl_ipythonnb.ipynb

The GSL libraries are located in the following directories:

```
-I/usr/local/include
-L/usr/local/lib -lgsl
```

I know that similar questions have been asked on SO before, but I couldn't find one relevant to my situation and system (I'm using OS-X).  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't get this to work at all on my system (IPython version, maybe---I'm on 1.2).  Try adding the -I and -L args to the `%%cython` line; this http://goo.gl/kUzoiE says `-I` arguments can be put there, and it seems plausible `-L` will be fine too.